# How to execute AJAX on button click in php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a WordPress plugin and I have added some elements on admin settings using php file. Now I want to execute a php function on button click and after searching on internet, AJAX seemed like a way to go. But I don't know AJAX at all. So here is some code I put together.
And I know this code may seem messed up but please take a look.

```
echo"<form method='POST' action='temp.php'>";

function slideyglidey_settings_section_callback() {
  esc_html_e( 'Plugin settings section description', 'slideyglidey' );
}
function slideyglidey_settings_input_file_callback() {
  $options = get_option( 'slideyglidey_settings' );
    $file_input = '';
    if( isset( $options[ 'file_input' ] ) ) {
        $file_input = esc_html( $options['file_input'] );
    }
  echo '<input type="file" id="slideyglidey_fileinput" 
  name="slideyglidey_settings[file_input]" value="' . $file_input . '" 
  onchange="onFileSelected(event)" />';
  } 
 function slideyglidey_settings_img_src_callback() {
   $options = get_option( 'slideyglidey_settings' );
    $img_src = '';
    if( isset( $options[ 'img_src' ] ) ) {
        $img_src = esc_html( $options['img_src'] );
    }
  echo '<img src="" id="slideyglidey_imgsrc" 
  name="slideyglidey_settings[img_src]" value="' . $img_src . '" width="350" 
  height="200"/>';
  }
 function slideyglidey_settings_upload_btn_callback() {
   $options = get_option( 'slideyglidey_settings' );
   $upload_btn = '';
   if( isset( $options[ 'upload_btn' ] ) ) {
     $upload_btn = esc_html( $options['upload_btn'] );
   }

   echo '<input type="button" id="slideyglidey_uploadbtn" 
   name="slideyglidey_settings[upload_btn]" value="Upload"/>';
  }

 echo"</form>";
 ?>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script> 
      var $checkboxes = $( "form input:file" )
      $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
            var st="helloHOWAREYOU";


        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "temp.php",
          cache: false,
          data: 'name=' + st,
          success: function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);
          }
        });
      })
    </script>
```

**temp.php**

```
<?php 
  $name = $_POST['name'];
   echo '<script>console.log($name)</script>';
?>
```

When I execute this code, I get no errors but I don't get the message in console log as well.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to pass data

```
    $.ajax({
    ...
    data : {name : 'helloHOWAREYOU'},
    ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your button:

```
echo  <button id="handler">click me</button>
```

Then put the following code in a `<script>` tag:

```js
document.getElementById('handler').addEventListener('click', AJAX);

function AJAX() {
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener("load", (data) => console.dir(data.target.response));
  req.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
  req.send();
}
```

```html
<button id="handler">click me</button>
```

Note I now perform the AJAX request to a website which offers some dummy data. Of course you have to change this to your own requirements.

Comment: Okay I'll try to integrate this code with mine and see how it works out. Thanks!